# sensitivity list in process in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

In the code below, what will be the simulation result if (select) is missing in the sensitivity lis?

```
process(a,b,select)
begin
if (select = '1') then 
output <= a;
else
output<=b;
end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Try simulating it and let us know what happens!  Here's a free online simulator: http://www.edaplayground.com/home

Comment: thanks . I am not that much sophisticated in VHDL. I am just trying to pass my exam on Monday. By the way thanks for your reply.

Comment: This won't work because `select` is a keyword.

Comment: ok . suppose sel instead of select.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a latch, instead of a multiplexer.

Your process is currently run if `sel` changes, because it's in the sensitivity list. The process then decides whether `a` or `b` should be routed to the output; this is a classical mux. The output potentially changes whenever `a`, `b`, or `sel` changes, and it's completely combinatorial.

If you take `sel` out of the sensitivity list, the process will not run when `sel` changes. The code would only examine the current state of `sel` when either `a` or `b` changes; it's just ignored at any other time. What this does (in physical hardware terms) is complex, but note that there must be memory involved. The simulator (or the correct hardware) effectively memorises the value of `sel` when `a` or `b` changes, and then ignores the current value of `sel` until there's another change on `a` or `b`.